# Explode array comma but not inside square brackets

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a string:

```
$var = "[Item 1],[Item 2],[Item, 3]";
```

When I use explode:

```
$var = explode(",", $var);
```

This also explodes out the comma inside the square brackets.

I would like to return:

```
[Item 1]
[Item 2]
[Item, 3]
```

Running through a foreach () {} statement which I am using. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$var = "[Item 1],[Item 2],[Item, 3]";

$var = explode("],[", $var);

print_r($var);
```

--doh forgot that the delimiter is lost so um a crude option to put those [] back in:

```
<?php
$var = "[Item 1],[Item 2],[Item, 3]";

$var = explode("],[", $var);

foreach ($var as $v){

  if(substr($v,0,1)!='['){
   $v='['.$v; 
  }

    if(substr($v,-1)!=']'){
$v=$v.']'; 
  }

    $out[]=$v; 



}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

may be better to switch to a regular expression split, i'll write that in a sec

FINIAL sexy answer:

```
<?php
$var = "[Item 1],[Item 2],[Item, 3]";


$var = preg_split('/(\B,\B)/', $var);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($var);
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/6qgSzB

Answer (score 0):

It will not work which you want. But it can be done with

```
$var = "[Item 1],[Item 2],[Item, 3]";

$varArr = explode("],", $var);

$newArr= array();
foreach($varArr as $key=>$val)
    $newArr[$key] = $val . "]";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using regular expression to extract those information?

```
$var = "[Item 1],[Item 2],[Item, 3]";
preg_match_all("(\[.+?\])", $var, $result);

print_r($result[0]);
```